# recursively run a command and check to see if it exists

Tags: windows, batch-processing

On a Windows Env, I'm trying to find a way to recursively check all files in a dirtree to see if they filename/size match a list of files in another dir, if they do exist in the dir, then it runs a command on the file found

Psudocode:

```
Loop{
If(RecursivelyFindFiles() = FileInFileListingInResources()) {

DoCommand(cmd1 -D -R -N %FoundFile C:\resources\%Filename)

}

}
```

I know what i want, just dont know how to do it on a Windows Env

Answer (score 1):

```
@echo off
for /r %root% %%f in (*.*) do if exist ..\folder\%%~nxf call :furthertests %%f folder\%%~nxf
goto :eof

:furthertests
echo %1 found
if not "%~z1"=="%~z2" goto :eof
echo file sizes match (%~z1 bytes)
@rem Do your stuff with %1 here
@rem ...
```

Assumes `%root%` is start of search tree, and `..\folder\` contains the prototype files.

Comment: wow, it seems you've done it :) I've learn something about batch file today !

Answer (score 0):

here is a start !

```
@echo off
rem %1 First folder
rem %2 Other folder to compare
FOR /R %1 IN (*.*) DO echo %%G
echo Done!
```

Instead of the `echo %%G`, you can call `fc %%G ABC` which is a filecompare exe. But I don't know how to format **ABC** to be the Path to folder 2 (%2) + base filename of %%G.
After, a `if` test to the result of `fc` and you can call your processing.

I'm sorry, I admit I must stop here !